# Using vector drawable as Android app icon

Tags: android, kotlin, android-manifest, android-jetpack-compose, android-drawable

After creating an Android Studio 'Phone and Tablet' project using Material3 for Jetpack Compose, there appears to be a superfluous amount of image files created, despite the minimum API being 30 (Android 11). Why in the `mipmap` folder has a whole bunch of raster images been generated, when for years, developers have been encouraged to use vector drawables for their app icons? Even the XML files seem to be in a folder for API 26. Is that really necessary when an app targets API 30? What should be done with the files in the `ic_launcher` and `ic_launcher_round` folders ending in `.webp`?

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyVectorApp">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**'Project' pane in Android Studio**

[image]

Comment: There’s a huge difference between target SDK version and min SDK version, but you seem to be using the terms interchangeably. Are you sure your `minSdkVersion` is 30? Doesn’t look like it from your screenshot.

Comment: @Tenfour04 it certainly is. What were you expecting?

Answer (score -1):

1. WebP is an image format that is developed by Google, focuses mainly on optimization and quality, more on that [here](https://proandroiddev.com/webp-a-preferred-image-format-for-android-apps-251a0ab1aa70)
2. those generated images are pretty necessary, because they allow the apps icon to adapt to screen size, as shown [here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities)

Comment: I thought the XML vector drawable files would be used? The Android Developers website encourages developers to use a single background file and a single foreground file. When would webp and xml be used (in which situations)?

Comment: single background and foreground file might just be a reference to the proces of creating the icon, having multiple shapes overlaying with many colors in the background of an icon most of the times would not look pretty at all. Also, creating custom hdpi files (as mentioned above) allows the app icons to support different sizes and also is the modern way of setting icons, you could use .svg files for the app icons before android lollipop. Also, the answer to your second question basically can be found in the package names ;)

Comment: This answer is wrong for the situation the OP describes, where a vector image asset is provided and the min SDK version is high enough to ensure the device has vector support. There would be no need for raster images (like webp) in that case.

Comment: Well, firstly: My bad, misunderstood the question, secondly: Currently there isn't a way to declare a maximumSdkVersion (that are checked by android itself, not google play), so generating those icons could prevent some android related errors (due to no icon being present) whenever the app is installed on newer devices